# How to perform VECM with known cointegrating vecotor using R

Tags: r

could anybody help me out with this? I have found the cointegrating vector using DOLS, and now I want to impose that cointegrating vector in the VECM model, could I still use functions in `urca` or `var` packages? Or do I have to run OLS by myself? Since I would like to transfer VECM into VAR and then to VMA afterwards, I am hoping to use the functions in packages rather than write those all by myself. Thanks~~~~ Jiaheng

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `tsDyn` package? It has a function called VECM which allows you to do this.

Comment: Just referring someone to a function isn't really an answer. Of course the question didn't help very much, did he? At the moment there is no code or data in either the Q or the A.